# __repr__ for an attribute that can be a string or None?

Tags: python, repr

Given this simple class:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,a=None):
        self.a = a
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Foo(a='{self.a}')".format(self=self)
```

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to get the `__repr__` to return different formatting depending on the type of a:

```
Foo('some_string') # if a is a string
Foo(5)             # if a is the integer 5
Foo(None)          # if a is None
```

Obviously, for a single attribute I could test and have different output strings but I am thinking that someone must have tackled this before me. Specifically, I have several attributes that can be strings or None and I don't see that writing complicated logic for my `__repr__` makes much sense.

Comment: Thanks to Martijn for the quick answer! Now, does anyone have any "tricks" for dealing with optional parameters? I'm thinking that Foo() is much prettier than Foo(None)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `repr()` of `self.a`:

```
return "Foo(a={self.a!r})".format(self=self)
```

The `!r` tells `.format()` to call `repr()` on `self.a`, instead of calling `__format__()` on the value, see [Format String syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> '{!r}'.format(0)
'0'
>>> '{!r}'.format('foo')
"'foo'"
```

Demo:

```
>>> Foo(0)
Foo(a=0)
>>> Foo('foo')
Foo(a='foo')
>>> Foo(None)
Foo(a=None)
```

Comment: You probably want to drop the quotes to `"Foo(a={self.a!r})"`

Answer (score 2):

While I accepted Martijn's answer, I wanted to explicitly show the results of his suggestion a little more clearly:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, a=None, b=None):
...         self.a = a
...         self.b = b
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Foo(a={self.a!r}, b={self.b!r})'.format(self=self)
...      
>>> Foo(a='a')
Foo(a='a', b=None)
>>> Foo(a=5)
Foo(a=5, b=None)
```